# Jenkins "Project Path" SCM

Tags: jenkins, tfs

I'm trying to set up a parameterized build. 
One of the build parameters is the branchname, where I want the TFS plugin to get the project from.

Is it possible to pass an build parameter to the "project path" variable of the TFS SCM plugin. (If yes, how? I have tried several ways, but it doesn't seem to work)

This variable:
[TFS Project Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01QEE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to use variable for Project path in Jenkins. The Project Path requires the name of the project as it is registered on the server. There is nowhere to define the variable.

The description of Project path is:

> The Team Project and path to retrieve from the server. The project
>   path must start with $/, and contain any sub path that exists in the
>   project repository.

Check: https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "build-parameter":
[image: definition of the variable for this build]

and user this parameter in the TFS-settings:

[image: usage of variable in TFS-setting]

But in my case I want the TFS-plugin check the TFS for code changes every 15 minutes and trigger a build if code changes were detected. Using this configuration the plugin triggers the build every 15 minutes also if there are no code changes.