# How can we update Project Path in Jenkins for the SCM as TFS on demand? If there is any method for Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, tfs

In the HUDSON's TFS plugin documentation for TFS SCM "http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/tfs/hudson/plugins/tfs/TeamFoundationServerScm.html " there is a method [getProjectPath()](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/tfs/hudson/plugins/tfs/TeamFoundationServerScm.html#getProjectPath--)

But there is no method to set the Project path.

**Can someone help me with a groovy to update/set/change the project path as and when required?**

Answer (score 0):

`Preoject Path` the path in TFVC to download from, where you want the TFS plugin to get the project from.

If you'd like to set up a parameterized build,to dynamically change the "project path" variable of the TFS SCM plugin. This is not able to do this, please take a look at [Jenkins "Project Path" SCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38433412/jenkins-project-path-scm). You could only get a changeset number for the source branch, such as: [Jenkins Get Source Code By Specific TFS Changeset](https://automatetheplanet.com/jenkins-get-source-code-by-specific-tfs-changeset/)

If you just want configure a TFS job with TFS scm configuration and use DSL plug-in, more details please have a look at this thread: [How do you configure a TFS job with the Jenkins Job DSL plugin?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1c4c044b-f042-4d45-9b33-d2661429938f/how-do-you-configure-a-tfs-job-with-the-jenkins-job-dsl-plugin?forum=tfsversioncontrol)

Comment: [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38433412/jenkins-project-path-scm  :- This says we cannot do it dynamically. I have already configured the jobs as per the flow. Thanks. But doesn't solve the purpose. Why is the Hudson-TFS plugin matured for this.